# awk counting delimiter didnt go as expected

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I was on counting the number of delimiters which is '|@~' from my client data, actually I have to do this because sometimes I received less or more delimiters. I used to use this syntax to find the number of delimiters per row :

```
awk -F "|@~" '{print NF-1}' myDATA
```

it usually work, but somehow today it returns only 2 counts, meanwhile I expected 6. After I check the data manually, I can see 6 delimiter there, afterwards I tried to copy manually the row and paste it to the notepad++ , surprisingly not all the lines being copied, only some lines, and surprisingly it contains only 2 delimiter, as the script gave me. What make this happen ?

What I see and I want to copy : `0123|@~123123|@~21321303|@~00000009213123|@~ 002133123123.|@~ 000000000.|@~CITY`

Paste result : `0123|@~123123|@~21321303`

missing paste : `|@~00000009213123|@~ 002133123123.|@~ 000000000.|@~CITY`

It seems there is something in between 3rd delimiter with last character of 3rd field, because I have to split copy it 2 times into this site, it makes sense with the awk result that returns only 2 |@~ delimiters, but of course it is 6 not 2.

Comment: Your [code says `6`](https://ideone.com/iPxLSd). You must have failed to copy the exact text you have.

Comment: yes, it returns 6 for this one, but I have said that I tried to split copy this one line, to make that happen (copying to this site), actually the original text it returns 2 not 6 using awk, and if I tried copy like using CTRL+A > CTRL+C > CTRL+V, it only copy the PASTE RESULT. Is awk not powerful enough, or because it detects some character that cant be seen by human eyes, somehow it returns 2, not 6, maybe the next character of 3rd field (right before 3rd delimiter) is a command to delete the rest line?

Comment: Can you post a hexdump of the problematic line? The text might contain control characters. Use `hexdump -c` to see them easily.

Comment: You set `FS` with `-F="|@~"`. Be careful, if `FS` is more then one character long, it is treated as a regular expression. the pipe (`|`) has a special meaning here. So it is better to use `-F=\\|@~`. You need to double escape the `|` here due to the [gory escape details](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html)

Comment: @Socowi somehow i tried to find hex editor on the web, he said something like "your record got 00h, which interpreted by windows clipboard as text termination. Does it mean I cant resovle this with awk? because awk works the same as windows clipboard which terminate the records after 3rd field right next to 3rd delimiter?

Comment: If 00h means a nullbyte then use `tr -d \\0 < brokenInputFile > fixedOutputFile` to remove those. `awk` would be overkill for such a small task.

Comment: @Socowi could you post this as an answer, finally I know that the record got null values which terminates the process to count for the remaining text.

Comment: @KarsaZ I'm glad this solved your problem. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your [hexdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919131/awk-counting-delimiter-didnt-go-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment116550946_65919131) revealed, there are null bytes in your text file.

GNU Awk 4.1.4 and 5.1.0 seem to threat these as the end of the file. Example:

```
$ awk '{print NF}' <<< $'a b c\nx y'
3
2
$ awk '{print NF}' <<< $'a\0 b c\nx y'
1
```

In `man awk` I haven't found  a way to change this behavior. However, you probably don't want the null bytes in your file to begin with. Therefore you can just delete them before applying `awk`. To delete all null bytes from a file use this command:

```
tr -d \\0 < /path/to/broken/input/file > /path/to/fixed/output/file
```

Comment: A lot of awk implementations use c-strings which are known to have problems with null bytes. This is most likely related. I do believe that GNU awk treats strings differently. Nonetheless, I cannot see this issue in 4.2.x or even 4.0.x